# DataTables momentjs sorting plugin doesn't sort AM/PM times properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables, momentjs

I have some timestamped data that I'm displaying in a table with [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and I'm using its [momentjs date sorting plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment#top) to order the date/time column properly.

It's working on a page that only has a date but on the page that shows a date and time, it's ignoring AM and PM times.

So if a record was entered at 7:00 AM, it gets sorted as if it were later than another record entered at 6:30 PM.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with the plugin/momentjs?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'); //registers the date format we're using as sortable

    $('#<%=gvNotes.ClientID%>').dataTable({
        "order": [[1, 'desc']],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }, //disable sorting on the "edit" column
            { "type": "date", "targets": $('#<%=hfDateColumnNum.ClientID%>').val() } //date column formatted like "03/23/2018 10:25:13 AM"
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a working fiddle showing your issue?

Comment: @Yuri - Hmm... it works in the fiddle. The only difference is that in my non-working code, the value of `"targets"` for the date type is dynamically generated. My problem has to be there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. In my updated sample code above, the `targets` value for the date type was dynamically generated and stored in a hidden field.

Calling `val()` was returning the correct value but it was being parsed as a string rather than an integer, causing the code not to operate correctly. Using `parseInt()` fixed the problem.

Here's the updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'); //registers the date format we're using as sortable

    $('#<%=gvNotes.ClientID%>').dataTable({
        "order": [[1, 'desc']],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }, //disable sorting on the "edit" column
            { "type": "date", "targets": parseInt($('#<%=hfDateColumnNum.ClientID%>').val()) } //date column formatted like "03/23/2018 10:25:13 AM"
        ]
    });
});
```